# Proof that plane with $N$ lines can be painted with two colors so that any two neighboring regions are painted in different colors

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$N$ lines are drawn in a plane. Proof that we can paint all the sectors in $2$ different colors, so any two neighbors (border's length is $>0$ (not just a point) ) are in different colors?

I am really stuck with this one. Any tips? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

That's a classical combinatorial geometry problem with a very nice solution: we do it by induction on the number of lines.

When there's 1 line, it's easy.

Next, suppose we've succeeded for $n$ lines. Then add more line and invert all colors on one side of it :) You can fill in the details.

Comment: Cloud you please tell me the name of the problem or tell me where i can read more about it ? Thank you :)